# Display multiple Outlook Addins under same grouplabel in ribbon

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I created 2 addins for outlook using Officejs. Now the client wants the 2 addins to be grouped under the same group(name) in the ribbon.

I tried changed the grouplabel to the same value, but unfortunatly this created 2 groups with the same name instead of regrouping them.

Is it possible to group them together?

Comment: Are you talking about two add-ins under same groupLabel or two different features of a single add-in under a groupLabel ? 

If you want different features under a same add-in you can do it using Group. 
Inside a Group, you can provide different control for different features. 

Please refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1

You can create as many features as you want using different controls inside a group.

Comment: I'm talking about two seperate addins under the same group label (some users will have access to both, but most only to one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the feature: Multiple add-ins under same group label ribbon, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our  user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins